# How to highlight edited text from the datagridview cell using Richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, richtextbox

I have a datagridview which I inserted the Richtextbox whith a goal of changing the color from the cell that contains datatridview

I have asked this question before but i didn't get help as didn't post the code or shows what i have tried before. now i have done reach on richtexbox on how it works

to make this more understandable.

1.will load the file to the datagediview
2. file will be loaded with the data on it
3. I have inserted richtextbox to comment column cell

All this works fine with no problem.

now this is i want to get after all

1.from the data that is being loaded to the datagrdview

2.column that contains richtext box, it will be with the data

3.from that column, i want to edit the data and highlight only edited words or text after changes to red(this will happen automatically after edit)

4.the color must but red for those changes i made to the text

5.e.g Test = Testing

6.from the example above, "**ing**" will be highlighted in red

7.this is to track the changes that was made

can anyone please help me with the coding if possible, i am really stuck for days now please!

Adding richtextbox to the grid. it only works if i wrote "blush" from the textbox but when i typed from the grid it doesn't appear. I don't know how i can make it work on the grid... please healp

```
    public void Addrichtext()
    {

        RichTextBox rtbox = new RichTextBox();
        Gridview_Output.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = rtbox.Text;

        string words = "blush";
        if (rtbox.Text.Contains(words.ToString()))
        {
            rtbox.Select(rtbox.Text.IndexOf(words.ToString()), words.ToString().Length);
            rtbox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void ReadFile(ref DataGridView _Grid, ref TextBox _InputTexBox, ref ComboBox _cboLanguage, ref  Button _btnNew)
    {
        _Grid.Rows.Clear();
        string PathSelection = "";
        if (_InputTexBox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            PathSelection = _InputTexBox.Text;
        }
        oDataSet = new DataSet();
        XmlReadMode omode = oDataSet.ReadXml(PathSelection); 

        for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            string font = Between(comment, "[Font]", "[/Font]");
            string datestamp = Between(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
            string commentVal = Between(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");
            string[] row = new string[] { oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(), oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(), font, datestamp, commentVal };
            _Grid.Rows.Add(row);
            _btnNew.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Please do advise if you need me to post other codes, like loading,reading and saving the file. am just saving the space

Comment: Please share the code that shows how you defined the datagrid

Comment: please see the update and tell me if that's the code needed

Comment: let me see if I can help, will revert back to you.

Comment: Thanks man...i will be waiting

Comment: Sorry man things got too hectic for me yesterday, I just sent you an email.